# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS recognizing but not playing DVD Movie

Tags: 14.04, dvd

so I enabled the restricted DVD codecs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and my DVD reader/writer recognizes the THE_MATRIX dvd, but it does not show any contents as if it were empty.

Any suggestions?
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 installed
as well as 
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

Comment: You try running your video player from the command line with a --verbose option to see why it can't play the DVD or if it is having issues?

Comment: @Mookey - here is a link : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu - often it is only about a missing library like libdvdcss (codecs) or the version of libdvdcss might be a bit too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `libdvdread4`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

then run this command.

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

now open up `VLC`

Click on <kbd>Media</kbd> --> <kbd>Open Disc</kbd> untick No disc menus then click <kbd>play</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There was actually no need for the last step, only a reboot after the commands. Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!