# No DVD Drive showing on left side in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, video, vlc, dvd

I tried and read all these below questions and answers-:

[My folder left side panel is missing in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176990/my-folder-left-side-panel-is-missing-in-nautilus)

[Can't play DVDs with Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094400/cant-play-dvds-with-ubuntu-18-04)

[Can't play DVDs through either VLC, Videos, or Kaffeine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013292/cant-play-dvds-through-either-vlc-videos-or-kaffeine)

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS recognizing but not playing DVD Movie](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710983/ubuntu-14-04-lts-recognizing-but-not-playing-dvd-movie)

No of above answers are working in my case and i am new to linux.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You should add your version of ubuntu to the post, some more information if the drive is recognized at all and what kind of drive it is.

Comment: If you open Disks does it show CD/DVD drive present there? For me it does but nothing is reported in nautilus if the drive is empty. 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the drive is mounted. You can check the mounted devices using the command:

```
fdisk -l
```

You can mount devices using the command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda# /media/FolderName
```

but where you replace `#` (hash) with the partition number of the partition on the device you want to mount. For example, you might write `/dev/sda1`. The specific number you should put in place of `#` can be found in the outut of `fdisk -l`.

See [How to mount a drive from terminal in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/134734/how-to-mount-a-drive-from-terminal-in-ubuntu) (on Super User) for further information on mounting a drive and checking if a drive is mounted.

(If the device is mounted and still not showing in Nautilus, feel free to reply and I'll offer further troubleshooting steps.)